# program NSTouchBar with c++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, nstouchbar

## The problem

I would like to use c++ to create an application that uses the new macbook pro touch bar. However I am not able to find any really good resources. And apple does not have any docs on using c++ to program the touch bar.

## What I have done

I found [this](http://svenandersson.se/2017/getting-nstouchbar-to-play-nice-with-glfw.html) article on c++ and the touch bar, However I cannot find either of the header files for the script `GLFW/glfw3.h` and `GLFW/glfw3native.h`. These both seem critical to the script working.

## More on the issue

Even if the above article's script works, there are no *official* docs for programing the touch bar with c++ (That I know of). I think that this is an important thing to have given the fact that many, if not most applications are written in c/c++.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the article that you link to basically does not need the `GLFW/glfw3.h` and `GLFW/glfw3native.h` files if you are not using GLFW.

What UI framework are you using for your C++ app?

Unless it is still using Carbon, at the lowest level, the framework will be creating NSWindows to actually have windows in the UI. You need to get access to the NSWindow that  your framework is using to host it the UI. If it is still using Carbon, I think you are probably not going to be able to accomplish this.

If the framework provides some mechanism to get the native platform window (which will be an NSWindow), you would replace the author's call to `glfwGetCocoaWindow(window);` with the correct call from your framework.

If the framework does not provide access to the NSWindow, then you will need to use the code that is commented out at the bottom of the article to attach your touchbar to the windows in your app.

Please note that all that code is Obj-C code; you'll need to have at least one `.m` or `.mm` file in your project to provide that Obj-C glue code to get access to the touchbar. Basically that code is a C-calleable wrapper around the Cocoa API.

Also note that you'll need to expand the list of buttons and actions for all the different things you want to put in the touchbar. You could add your own wrapping API so that the construction of the toolbar is done from C++ and registers actions that call-back into your C++ app to handle the events.

Fundamentally though, the touchbar is not available on any other platform, so there is no great benefit to trying to avoid writing Obj-C to implement your touchbar as that code will only run on macOS anyway. If you use `.mm` files to implement Obj-C++ for this code, you can still call into your C++ objects from your touchbar code.

Comment: Other than that you have to learn Objective-C first!
--------
there is no great benefit to trying to avoid writing Obj-C

Comment: @David, the API is fundamentally a Obj-C/Swift API. If your want to access the API, you'll have to use some Obj-C. It may simply be easier to write the touchbar support using the Obj-C than writing an Obj-C++ wrapper around it just so you can interface to it via C++; again, at the end of the day, this code is not going to be portable to other platforms; might as well use the API directly...

Comment: Uh, yeah, --- hence the request from the OP for a C++ wrapper. Presumably he was hoping someone had already wrapped it so that he wouldn't have to learn Obj-C!  Just because something isn't portable doesn't mean you should have to write in Obj-C.

_______
the API is fundamentally a Obj-C/Swift API

Comment: Well, someone does. He didn't ask for a wrapper; he asked how to do it from C++. Anyway, unless someone writes a wrapper and publishes it, the answer is: you have to use Obj-C.